# Need help connecting my 8087 Backplane to normal SATA Ports

Tags: storage, sas, sata

- **Motherboard**: [SuperMicro MBD-X10SL7-F-O](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813182821)
- **Chassis**: [Norco RPC-3216](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811219034)
- **Hard Drives**: [WD Red 2TB NAS HDD](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822236343)
- **Breakout Cables**: [Norco Reverse Breakout Cables](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816133033)

This is a FreeNAS server I put together at home and is running in my garage.  It has been running a few years and I am now wanting to expand it's storage capacity.  Disks are managed by ZFS.

As of right this moment, I have 8 of the above-linked HDDs connected to the motherboard's SATA Ports controlled by the board's SAS Controller (Blue ports on the board itself) using two of the above-linked breakout cables.  Has been working great for me for a few years now.

I recently purchased 2 more of the same HDDs linked above to add into the system along with a new reverse breakout cable (the same as the one linked above).  I am currently trying to connect them to SATA Ports controlled by the SATA Controller (Black ports on the board itself).

While the system continues to see the 8 original drives, the BIOS does not detect the two new drives.  They also do not light up when the system is powered on like the other drives do (LED indicators on the front of the chassis on each hotswap bay).

As far as I understand it, what I'm doing is completely possible and the above is how to achieve it

What am I doing wrong here?  In the end, I'd like to have up to 16 of the drives linked above connected to this board.  I'd settle for just getting the two brand new drives in there.

Answer (score 0):

The backplane is powered by molex connectors.  The third and fourth molex connectors were from a separate line from the PSU.  That entire line is bad.  Replacing the line fixed my issue.